# confirmation codes in email

Tags: mysql

I have no idea where to start with this one. I have a confirmation code that gets created and stored in my database. When I copy that code from my database and paste it into my webpage it says it is wrong. How is that possible. It was working then just stopped. I don't even know what to show you, so let me know what you need to see.

If this helps, my login doesn't work either. it says that the username or password doesn't match when I get that from the database.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a five or ten-line script?

Comment: Is this on a server? If so, what kind - IIS/Apache? Is the system that creates confirmations code a web app written in PHP or Ruby etc? Based on a framework/CMS like Drupal, Wordpress, Rails, Zend etc? Is it logging into the database that you can't do, or logging on to your web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake, I had to change name to username

Comment: If your problem is solved, then set your own answer as accepted.